# Can I use a benchmark to choose a clustering or module detection method for a gene dataset?

Tags: gene-expression, clustering

The paper [A comprehensive evaluation of module detection methods for gene expression data](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-03424-4#Sec19) says that: "We first want to provide an overview of the characteristics and performance of current module detection methods to guide the biologist in their choice".

My problem is that I have no gold standards for my gene dataset and I would like to know if I can use the paper results to choose a module detection method without the need of external validation measures and how can I justificate this generalization? I am not finding the justificative about how can I use this guiding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does your dataset compare to the dataset in the paper? Without that information we can't answer the question (as noted also in your previously posted SE bio question).